# PHPstorm - change theme of ENTIRE program, not just code editor

Tags: php, phpstorm

I know I can go to **Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Appearance & Behaviour | Appearance | Theme** and change between `default` and `darcula`.

And I know I can change the editor color scheme by going to **Settings (Preferences on Mac) | IDE Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts**.

But how do I get different skins for the *entire* program? As in, other options than `default` and `darcula`?

Or are those the only two options?

I know I can download editor color schemes at [PHPStorm-Themes.com](http://phpstorm-themes.com/). But those themes only seem to change the color scheme of the editor itself. I want a different color scheme for the entire program.

Comment: Nowhere. I mean -- It's called "Look and Feel" (LAF) for Java Swing .. but not every LAF will work correctly with PhpStorm .. especially with current/latest versions .. as LAFs require tons of workarounds across all UI to work properly. https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5478204#5478204 ; https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5317207

Answer (score 1):

See https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kirillcool/archive/2005/08/intellij_idea_5.html for instructions. But, as @LazyOne mentioned, creating a custom LAF is a tricky task, and adding third-party LAF will likely break the UI